# In pytorch, which part cost most time? Loss calculation or backward+step?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

In pytorch, which part cost most of time?

1. Loss calculation(no backward, just calculating)
2. backward
3. step
   Please explain a bit if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just in Pytorch, but in all framework, `backward_step` takes more time

Comment: Thanks, But backward or step, which part cost more time?

Comment: `backward()` in gradient computation during backprop